# c++ error: An object not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, g++

Could anyone please explain me why I get the following error?

```
A.cpp: In member function ‘void A::NewObject(int)’:
A.cpp:11: error: ‘list_a’ was not declared in this scope
```

I tried declaring list_a i various places. Now it is in prog.cpp, in main(). I don't get it why it isn't allegedly in the scope.

My simplified code is below. My idea was to add (NewObject) an object of a class A to a list (Add) while additionally performing some sort of a test (Compare) defined within the A class.

I am a C++ beginner so I'd especially appreciate detailed answers. Thanks in advance.
Here are the files:

```
//A.h

#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A
{
private:
    int id;
    int Compare(int, int);
public:
    A()
    {
        id = 0;
    }
    A(int i)
    {
        id = i;
    }
    void NewObject(int i);
};
#endif

//A.cpp

#include "A.h"
#include "List.h"

void A::NewObject(int i)
{   
    list_a->Add(i);
}

int A::Compare(int a, int b)
{
    if ( a>b ) return 1;
    if ( a<b ) return -1;
    else return 0;
}


//List.h

#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    T* dana;
    Node *nxt, *pre;
    Node()
    {
        nxt = pre = 0;
    }
    Node(const T el, Node *n = 0, Node *p = 0 )
    {
        dana = el; nxt = n; pre = p;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class List
{
public:
    List()
    {
        head = tail = 0;
    }
    void Add(const U);
protected:
    Node<T> *head,*tail;
};

#endif


//List.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

template<typename T, typename U>
void List<T,U>::Add(const U el)
{
    int i = 5;
    Node<T> *hlp = new Node<T>();
    head = hlp;
    if ( Compare(el,i) > i )
        std::cout << "Ok" << std::endl;
}

//prog.cpp
#include "List.h"
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    List<class A, int> *list_a = new List<class A, int>();
    A obj;

    obj.NewObject(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is simple: you have never declared a variable named list_a in class A. Thats it.

Do it that way:

```
class A
{
private:
    List <int> list_a;
    int id;
    int Compare(int, int);
public:
    A()
    {
        id = 0;
    }
    A(int i)
    {
        id = i;
    }
    void NewObject(int i);
};
```

Remove the U template parameter from your list class.

Comment: I had to double check just to make sure on that one.

Comment: Yes, it is in the scope of main(). The scope of line 11 is local to that function; functions do not share local variables. Remember that main() is a function just like any other, it's just the first one called

Comment: Well now it's in prog.cpp, in main(). But I've tried declaring in A.cpp and it didn't work either. How should it look like and where should I place it then?

Comment: Yeah but it is accessed from class A and therefore the language expects it within the scope of class A. It has never been defined within that scope, so it is NOT in scope. Thats what the whole information hiding blablabla is all about...

Comment: For example as a member of A. Or you could pass it as (reference/pointer) parameter to A::NewObject

Comment: @cli_hlt yes, I understand but if I define it wherever in A.cpp I get `A.o: In function ` `A::NewObject(int)':
A.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to ` `List<A, int>::Add(int)'` ...

Comment: @anonymous_infoholic Remove the U template parameter. Your list needs only T, the actual type stored. Try again, you will see it will work.

Comment: @cli_hlt If I was to remove it only from the declaration of list_a, then the error says that the number of templates given is bad. If from the definition of class List itself, then I need U for for Add argument... Or do I miss something?

Comment: @DerManu : It wouldn't be good for it to be a member of A since List is to group in due time all A objects alike, no exception. Is there an alternative to passing as a pointer?

Comment: @anonymous_infoholic well you should add T's to your list, not U's. Make a template<typename T> List that stores T's. You do not really use the U's at all, do you?

Comment: @cli_hlt Quite a contrary. I use it in the code I provided. And in the version to come it will be crucial. A node will have a given object as a pointer (T) and the list will group all objects of a given class. U will be to pass the keys (id) of objects, which will form the basis for the order of the list; compare will be to compare those keys.

Comment: @anonymous_infoholic But your code is never using type U in any way...at least as I can see.

Comment: @cli_hlt : in List::Add i I pass U.

Comment: @anonymous_infoholic yeah you pass U, instatiate a Node<T> and Compare an U to a T - maybe you should rethink your design here...just my 2ct

Answer (score -1):

When this type of error occurs, there might be a mismatch of class name in the `main` function. Check whether they are same. Only then, you will get an error like `not declared in this scope`, which means "they are not declared properly".